# Swift/SpriteKit Access A Variable Of An Object + Remove A Node

Tags: swift, variables, collections, sprite-kit, collision-detection

So I have two objects that should lose health points at an collision.

```
    func addPlayer(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat){
    playerNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")

    playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: width/2)
    playerNode.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    playerNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    playerNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall | PhysicsCategory.Zombie
    playerNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall | PhysicsCategory.Zombie
    playerNode.name = "Player"

    player = Player(node: playerNode, healthPoints: 100, attack: 10)
    playerNode.position.x = xPos
    playerNode.position.y = yPos
    playerNode.size = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    addChild(playerNode)
}

func addZombie(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat){
    zombieNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zombie")

    zombieNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: width/2)
    zombieNode.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    zombieNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Zombie
    zombieNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Zombie | PhysicsCategory.Player | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    zombieNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Zombie | PhysicsCategory.Player | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    zombieNode.name = "Zombie"

    zombie = Zombie(node: zombieNode, healthPoints: 50, attack: 5)
    Zombies.append(zombie!)
    zombieNode.position.x = xPos
    zombieNode.position.y = yPos
    zombieNode.size = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    addChild(zombieNode)
}
```

When a collision appears this function get activated:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
    if(firstBody.name == "Player" && secondBody.name == "Zombie"){
        changeHealthPointsForZombieWithNode(secondBody, points: player!.attack)
    } else if(firstBody.name == "Zombie" && secondBody.name == "Player"){
        changeHealthPointsForPlayer(secondBody, points: zombie!.attack)
        print(player!.healthPoints)
    }
}

func changeHealthPointsForZombieWithNode(node: SKSpriteNode, points: Int) {
    for zombie in Zombies {
        if zombie.node == node {
            zombie.healthPoints -= points
            print(zombie.healthPoints)
            if(zombie.healthPoints <= 0){
                zombieNode.removeFromParent()
            }
            return
        }
    }
}

func changeHealthPointsForPlayer(node: SKSpriteNode, points: Int) {
    player!.healthPoints -= points
    if(player!.healthPoints <= 0){
        playerNode.removeFromParent()
        gameOver = true
    }
}
```

I want to subtract the health points of the zombie depending on the attack of the player and other way around. When the player hits the zombie the zombie should lose life points. When the zombie hits the player the player should lose life points. Every player/zombie got health points and an attack value. How do you access them in my `didBeginContact` function? I also have multiple zombies stored here `var Zombies:[Zombie] = []` because every zombie should have its universal values. How is it possible that just the zombie I attack loses health points.

PS: My `class Player`looks like this:

```
class Player{
var node: SKSpriteNode
var xPos = CGFloat()
var yPos = CGFloat()
var healthPoints: Int
var attack: Int

init(node: SKSpriteNode, healthPoints: Int, attack: Int){
    self.node = node
    self.healthPoints = healthPoints
    self.attack = attack
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can do is compare your `firstBody` or `secondBody` object (one that would be zombie after checking) with `node` field in your `Zombie` object in loop like this:

```
func changeHelthPointsForZombieWithNode(node: SKSpriteNode, andPoints points: Int) {
    for zombie in Zombies {
        if zombie.node == node {
            zombie.healthPoints -= points
            return
        }
    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

    if(firstBody.name == "Player" && secondBody.name == "Zombie"){
        changeHelthPointsForZombieWithNode(secondBody, andPoints: Player.attack)
    } else if(firstBody.name == "Zombie" && secondBody.name == "Player"){
        changeHelthPointsForZombieWithNode(firstBody, andPoints: Player.attack)
    }
}
```

This will be work if `Zombie` is a `class` type object, if it `struct` object you will need to use `for var i = 0; i < Zombies.count; ++i` loop and call object field form `Zombies` with index `i`

Second you can append fields you need to change insede the nodes like this:

```
class ZombieNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var healthPoints: Int
    var attack: Int
    ...
    // create custom init method with this params
    ...
}
```

Then append to scene this objects of this type like this:

```
func addZombie(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat){
    var zombieNode = ZombieNode(imageNamed: "zombie", healthPoints: 100, attack: 10)

    ...
    ...  

    addChild(zombieNode)
}
```

And in this case you have access you need inside you find in `didBeginContact` method objects like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! ZombieNode
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! ZombieNode

    if(firstBody.name == "Player" && secondBody.name == "Zombie"){
        secondBody.helthPoints -= Player.attack
    } else if(firstBody.name == "Zombie" && secondBody.name == "Player"){
        firstBody.helthPoints -= Zombie.attack
    }
}
```

**Edits for new code:**

Your `zombie` objects are not removed from the scene because you have not deleted them. You have a variable `zombieNode`, whenever you create Zambia in this line of code:

```
zombieNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zombie")
```

you every time assign it a new value, and is a result `zombieNode` is a pointer to the last created node. This approach works with the player because it is single object, and did not accept for a set of objects. In fact every time when your zombie died you tryed to remove this last created object. Thats why this was not worked. To fix it you need to do the following:

First of all you need do remove this line of code:

```
var zombieNode = SKSpriteNode()
```

In your `addZombie` method create new nodes like this:

```
let zombieNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zombie")
```

And in `changeHealthPointsForZombieWithNode` method you can remove zombie nodes like this:

```
if(zombie.healthPoints <= 0){
    node.removeFromParent()
}
```

It would be good as well, remove objects from `Zombie` array when you remove the node.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Both solutions doesn't work sadly. #1: Creating another function kind of works, but I still get an error `Instance member 'attack' cannot be used on type 'Player'`

Comment: #2: Creating the node different doesn't work either or I misunderstood your answer. Creating it like this: `var zombieNode = ZombieNode(node: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zombie"), healthPoints: 50, attack: 5)` give me an error as well. Every other line claim to have no member '...'. For more information I included the `class Player`. The `class Zombie` looks the same.

Comment: @LukasKöhl Of course don't have to use `Player.attack` in the code, I took it from your question just as an example, you need to create an object of this type and work with this object. Add the object in your scene class or where you have method `addZombie` like `var player: Player?`, then in `addPlayer` method create it like you did it but for this global object: `player = Player(node: playerNode, healthPoints: 100, attack: 10)` Then you will call it params with `!` like `player!.attac`. And call my method like this: `changeHelthPointsForZombieWithNode(secondBody, andPoints: player!.attack)`

Comment: I do get no error now but it still has no effect. I'm going to do some testing tomorrow to see what is wrong.

Comment: @ alex_p So I made some more testing and these are the results. Every zombie has its own health points (perfects) and lose them individual at the collision. Problem Nr.1 it doesn't get removed. Secondly the player seems to lose health points by one or none zombie. Same is it with the zombie. There might be one or none that disappear. Do you have some solution for this problem? PS: I updated the code.

Comment: @LukasKöhl Very hard to understand what is the problem to these explanations, and the code that is. You can share the link to the project, and I'll see a whole that may be wrong

Comment: I really appreciate your work. Thats the link to my project. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jnklz4dixuyw30h/AAAYjQFm5YKmPAvps5bA9A9ka?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a progress but still not the solution. Zombies can be killed and will be removed from the screen (yay :D). On the other site those zombies that will be removed can't deal damage to the hero. And off all zombies there is at least one who doesn't lose health. And only this zombies are able to kill the player. Do you have a possible solution for this problem?

Comment: @LukasKöhl I honestly think that as part of the original question, I have already said more than enough, further analysis of the code is essentially a rewrite of your project for you, I advise to make the remaining problems in a separate question if you can not solve them yourself